# Django REST framework tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

Risking this question to be too generic...

What would be the advised use case types to test in a regular implementation of a `REST API` using the `djangorestframework` plugin?

Comment: This is basically a question about best practice, which is off topic for stack overflow. It's a matter of opinion. For integration tests, the minimum are smoke tests that make sure every endpoint returns a valid http response without error. Unit tests are less important IMO, since the basic units come from the framework, and that code has solid test coverage already.

Comment: Yup, that was the grey line I was hoping to avoid: suggestions vs opinion discussion. In any case, replies like yours are what I was hoping for. Thanks @Håken Lid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that I understand your question very well,

> Code without tests is broken as designed.

So each part of an application need test. you should test the functionality of each API with unit-test, and fortunately, Django rest framework has tools for this action

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

```
from django.urls import include, path, reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, URLPatternsTestCase


class AccountTests(APITestCase, URLPatternsTestCase):
    urlpatterns = [
        path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    ]

    def test_create_account(self):
        """
        Ensure we can create a new account object.
        """
        url = reverse('account-list')
        response = self.client.get(url, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), 1)
```

Comment: That seems like a hell of a good place to start, thanks. Quite frankly, it was a logical mindset I was looking for, so I apologise for the vagueness of the question. Thanks again @Mohammad Efazati